# Indent (i.e Tab) in Chrome dev tools console

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any button you can press to indent your code in Chrome dev tools. Tab doesn't work.

Comment: Er, no. But you can use Snippets in Sources panel to have a nicely formatted code. Current snippet may be executed by Ctrl-Enter.

Comment: Tab seems to work in Canary (Chrome 56).

Comment: @KayceBasques Glad to hear this. Thanks for your feedback and all your  articles on dev tools!